# Help with Bayes theorem question

Tags: probability, statistics, bayes-theorem

I am trying to understand how to apply Bayes Theorem to solve the following question:

A drug manufacturer claims that its roadside drug test will detect the presence of cannabis in the blood 90% of the time ( i.e. show a positive test for a driver who has smoked cannabis in the last 72 hours). However, the manufacturer admits that 10% of all cannabis-free drivers also will test positive. A national survey indicates that 20% of all drivers have smoked cannabis during the last 72 hours.

What is the probability that a driver has smoked cannabis in the last 72 hours if they have tested positive?

My understanding was this:

P(A): Smoked cannabis in last 72 hours (0.20)

P(B|A): Positive test for a driver who has smoked cannabis in last 72 hours (0.9)

I don't understand how to figure out (B), which should be population tested positive. Is the figure 10% correct? It only gives false positives. Thanks.

Comment: $P(B)=P(B|A)P(A)+P(B|\lnot A)P(\lnot A)$

Comment: Thank for that. My solution using this was 0.69...does this look correct to you?

Comment: Do you mean that was your solution for $P(B)$ or your solution for $P(A|B)$?

Comment: This was the solution for P(A|B)

Comment: You are correct.